# Why does a soda bottle foam or froth when dropped?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, reversibility

Secondly, if I do drop a soda bottle how long do I have to keep it for it to return to its original state or condition, I.e. safe to open without froth spraying everywhere; or is there some rule of Thermodynamics which states that reversibility is impossible in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait three or four minutes and let the pressure drop  or.....
If you feel lucky you can try tapping the can a dozen times, as is shown  on  this video https://youtu.be/NQYO3Dp8lCA